Powershell Script Controls are not loading correctly
I have a powershell script which shows a form upon execution in windows ise.When i select any radio button none of the conrtols in panel 2 loads, but when i close the form without closing windows ise and rerun the script upon selection of any radio button then the controls in panel 2 loads.How to ensure the control loads at the first time itself.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic


# Define a function that sets a global variable
function Set-GlobalVariable {
    $global:CommandsArrayList = @()
}


# Call the function to set the global variable
Set-GlobalVariable



function Clear-Panel2Controls {
    param (
        [System.Windows.Forms.Panel]$panel,
        [System.Windows.Forms.Label]$heading
    )

    # Collect controls to remove in a separate array to avoid modifying the collection while iterating
    $controlsToRemove = @()
    foreach ($control in $panel.Controls) {
        if ($control -ne $heading) {
            $controlsToRemove += $control
        }
    }

    # Remove and dispose collected controls
    foreach ($control in $controlsToRemove) {
        $panel.Controls.Remove($control)
        $control.Dispose()
    }
}
        
# Function to uncheck all radio buttons in a panel
function UncheckAllRadioButtons($section) {
    foreach ($control in $section.ContainerPanel.Controls) {
        if ($control -is [System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton]) {
            $control.Checked = $false
        }
    }
}


function Add-SectionWithControlsToPanel {
    param (
        [System.Windows.Forms.Panel]$Panel,
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Controls,
        [System.Drawing.Point]$SectionLocation,
        [System.Drawing.Size]$SectionSize,
        [string[]]$ExcludedControls = @()
    )

    # Add controls to the section panel, excluding any specified in $ExcludedControls
    foreach ($control in $Controls) {
        if ($control.Name -notin $ExcludedControls) {
            $Panel.Controls.Add($control)
        }
    }

    # Add the section panel to the main panel
    #$Panel.Controls.Add($sectionPanel)
}






# Create a inputpanel
$inputpanel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$inputpanel.Width = $panel2.Width - 20
$inputpanel.Height = $panel2.Height/3
$inputpanel.Top = 85
$inputpanel.Left = 10
$inputpanel.BackColor = "Gainsboro"



$outputpanel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$outputpanel.Width = $panel2.Width - 20
$outputpanel.Height = $panel2.Height/3
$outputpanel.Top = ($panel2.Height/3) + 125
$outputpanel.Left = 10
$outputpanel.BackColor = "Gainsboro"



# Create heading for Panel2, Section 1
$Section21Heading = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Section21Heading.Text = "Input"
$Section21Heading.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Section21Heading.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
$Section21Heading.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,60)
$Section21Heading.BackColor = "#20B2AA"
$Section21Heading.Width = 60


# Create heading for Panel2, Section 2
$Section22Heading = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Section22Heading.Text = "Output"
$Section22Heading.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Section22Heading.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
$Section22Heading.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,(($panel2.Height/3)+100))
$Section22Heading.BackColor = "#20B2AA"
$Section22Heading.Width = 60


# Create heading for Panel2, Section 1
$CountLbl = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$CountLbl.Text = "Count"
$CountLbl.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$CountLbl.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$CountLbl.Width = 50


# Create heading for Panel2, Section 1
$CountTxtbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$CountTxtbox.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8)
$CountTxtbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(60,20)
$CountTxtbox.Width = 30

# Create heading for Panel2, Section 1
$HopsLbl = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$HopsLbl.Text = "Hops"
$HopsLbl.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$HopsLbl.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100,20)
$HopsLbl.Width = 50


# Create heading for Panel2, Section 1
$HopsTxtbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$HopsTxtbox.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8)
$HopsTxtbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,20)
$HopsTxtbox.Width = 30


# Create heading for Panel2, Section 1
$HostLbl = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$HostLbl.Text = "HostBox"
$HostLbl.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$HostLbl.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(350,20)
$HostLbl.Width = 100

# Create heading for Panel2, Section 1
$HostTxtbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$HostTxtbox.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8)
$HostTxtbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(430,20)
$HostTxtbox.Width = 200
$HostTxtbox.Height = $inputpanel.Height - 50
$HostTxtbox.Multiline = $True
$HostTxtbox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"




# Create a scrollable text box in the bottom panel
$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Multiline = $true
$textBox.ScrollBars = [System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars]::Vertical
$textBox.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill
$textBox.BackColor = "Gainsboro"
$textBox.BorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::FixedSingle # Give the panel a 3D border





$ExecuteButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ExecuteButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (100,30)
$ExecuteButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$ExecuteButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,(($panel2.Height) - 180))
$ExecuteButton.ForeColor = "White"
$ExecuteButton.BackColor = "#005cb9"
$ExecuteButton.Text = "Execute"

# Add mouse event handlers for the button
$ExecuteButton.Add_MouseHover({
    # Change cursor to hand
    $form.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
    # Change button color
    $ExecuteButton.BackColor = "#404040"
})

$ExecuteButton.Add_MouseLeave({
    # Reset cursor to default
    $form.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Default
    # Reset button color
    $ExecuteButton.BackColor = "#005cb9"
})


$ClearButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ClearButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (100,30)
$ClearButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$ClearButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(300,(($panel2.Height) - 180))
$ClearButton.ForeColor = "White"
$ClearButton.BackColor = "#005cb9"
$ClearButton.Text = "Clear"

# Add mouse event handlers for the button
$ClearButton.Add_MouseHover({
    # Change cursor to hand
    $form.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
    # Change button color
    $ClearButton.BackColor = "#404040"
})

$ClearButton.Add_MouseLeave({
    # Reset cursor to default
    $form.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Default
    # Reset button color
    $ClearButton.BackColor = "#005cb9"
})




$ExportButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ExportButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (100,30)
$ExportButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$ExportButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(450,(($panel2.Height) - 180))
$ExportButton.ForeColor = "White"
$ExportButton.BackColor = "#005cb9"
$ExportButton.Text = "Export"

# Add mouse event handlers for the button
$ExportButton.Add_MouseHover({
    # Change cursor to hand
    $form.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
    # Change button color
    $ExportButton.BackColor = "#404040"
})

$ExportButton.Add_MouseLeave({
    # Reset cursor to default
    $form.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Default
    # Reset button color
    $ExportButton.BackColor = "#005cb9"
})









# Define a custom class for a scrollable section with radio buttons for Panel 1
class ScrollableSection1 {
    [System.Windows.Forms.Panel]$ContainerPanel
    

    ScrollableSection1([System.Windows.Forms.Panel]$parentPanel, [int]$topPosition){
        # Create the container panel
        $this.ContainerPanel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
        $this.ContainerPanel.Width = $parentPanel.Width - 50
        $this.ContainerPanel.Height = 100
        $this.ContainerPanel.Top = 85
        $this.ContainerPanel.Left = 10
        $this.ContainerPanel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::LightGray
        $this.ContainerPanel.AutoScroll = $true
        $parentPanel.Controls.Add($this.ContainerPanel)



        # Create radio buttons

        
            $global:PingradioButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
            $global:PingradioButton.Text = "Ping"
            $global:PingradioButton.Top = 10 + (1 - 1) * 25
            $global:PingradioButton.Left = 10
            $global:PingradioButton.AutoSize = $true
            $global:PingradioButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12)
            $this.ContainerPanel.Controls.Add($global:PingradioButton)
            


       
            $global:DNSradioButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
            $global:DNSradioButton.Text = "DNS"
            $global:DNSradioButton.Top = 20 + (2 - 1) * 25
            $global:DNSradioButton.Left = 10
            $global:DNSradioButton.AutoSize = $true
            $global:DNSradioButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12)
            $this.ContainerPanel.Controls.Add($global:DNSradioButton)

                              

            $global:TraceradioButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
            $global:TraceradioButton.Text = "Traceroute"
            $global:TraceradioButton.Top = 30 + (3 - 1) * 25
            $global:TraceradioButton.Left = 10
            $global:TraceradioButton.AutoSize = $true
            $global:TraceradioButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12)
            $this.ContainerPanel.Controls.Add($global:TraceradioButton)



    }


    # Method to format the section
    [void]FormatSection1([System.Drawing.Color]$backgroundColor, [System.Drawing.Color]$textColor) {
        $this.ContainerPanel.BackColor = $backgroundColor
        foreach ($radioButton in $this.RadioButtons) {
            $radioButton.ForeColor = $textColor
            
        }
    }
}



# Get screen dimensions
$screen = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::PrimaryMonitorSize
$screenWidth = $screen.Width
$screenHeight = $screen.Height

# Create the main form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
# Set default icon
$form.Text = "Tool"
$form.Width = $screenWidth
$form.Height = $screenHeight
# Set form properties to prevent resizing
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedDialog


# Calculate widths based on the ratio 0.5 : 2 : 0.5
$totalWidth = $form.ClientSize.Width
$panel1Width = [math]::Round($totalWidth * 0.5 / (0.5 + 2 + 0.5))
$panel2Width = [math]::Round($totalWidth * 2 / (0.5 + 2 + 0.5))
$panel3Width = $totalWidth - $panel1Width - $panel2Width






# Create Panel 1
$panel1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$panel1.Width = $panel1Width
$panel1.Height = $form.ClientSize.Height
$panel1.Top = 100
$panel1.BackColor = "#DCDCDC"
$panel1.AutoScroll = $true
$panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 12000)




# Create Panel 2
$panel2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$panel2.Width = $panel2Width
$panel2.Height = $form.ClientSize.Height
$panel2.Top = 100
$panel2.Left = $panel1Width
$panel2.BackColor = "#C0C0C0"
#$panel2.AutoScroll = $true



# Create Panel 3
$panel3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$panel3.Width = $panel3Width
$panel3.Height = $form.ClientSize.Height
$panel3.Top = 100
$panel3.Left = $panel1Width + $panel2Width
$panel3.BackColor = "#DCDCDC"
$panel3.AutoScroll = $true
$panel3.AutoScrollMinSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 12000)





# Create a banner header
$headerLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$headerLabel.Text = "Tool"
$headerLabel.Width = $screenWidth - ($panel1Width + $panel3Width)
$headerLabel.Height = 100
$headerLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($panel1Width, 0)
$headerLabel.BackColor = "#FBCE07"
$headerLabel.ForeColor = "#404040"
$headerLabel.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleCenter
$headerLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 36, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)





# Create heading for Panel 1
$panel1Heading = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$panel1Heading.Text = "Utilities"
$panel1Heading.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$panel1Heading.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White
$panel1Heading.BackColor = "#404040"
$panel1Heading.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
$panel1Heading.Height = 50
$panel1Heading.Width = $screenWidth - ($panel2Width + $panel3Width)
$panel1Heading.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0, 100)
$form.Controls.Add($panel1Heading)

# Create heading for Panel 2
$panel2Heading = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$panel2Heading.Text = "Workspace"
$panel2Heading.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$panel2Heading.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White
$panel2Heading.BackColor = "#404040"
$panel2Heading.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
$panel2Heading.Height = 50
$panel2Heading.Width = $screenWidth - ($panel1Width + $panel3Width)
$panel2Heading.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($panel1Width, 100)
$form.Controls.Add($panel2Heading)

# Create heading for Panel 3
$panel3Heading = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$panel3Heading.Text = "Login Details"
$panel3Heading.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$panel3Heading.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White
$panel3Heading.BackColor = "#404040"
$panel3Heading.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
$panel3Heading.Height = 50
$panel3Heading.Width = $screenWidth - ($panel1Width + $panel2Width)
$panel3Heading.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(1595, 100)
$form.Controls.Add($panel3Heading)


# Create heading for Panel1, Section 1
$Section1Heading = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Section1Heading.Text = "Network Diagnostic"
$Section1Heading.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 14, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Section1Heading.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,60)
$Section1Heading.ForeColor = "404040"
$Section1Heading.BackColor = "#FBCE07"
$Section1Heading.Width = 220
$panel1.Controls.Add($Section1Heading)







# Add scrollable sections with labels and radio buttons to panel 1
    $section1 = [ScrollableSection1]::new($panel1, 1 * 50)

 
    $section1.FormatSection1([System.Drawing.Color]::Silver, [System.Drawing.Color]::Black)


# Create an arraylist to hold Network Diagnostic controls
$controls = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$controls.Add($inputpanel) | Out-Null
$controls.Add($outputpanel)| Out-Null
$controls.Add($Section21Heading)| Out-Null
$controls.Add($Section22Heading)| Out-Null
$controls.Add($inputpanel.Controls.Add($CountLbl)) | Out-Null
$controls.Add($inputpanel.Controls.Add($HopsLbl)) | Out-Null
$controls.Add($inputpanel.Controls.Add($CountTxtbox)) | Out-Null
$controls.Add($inputpanel.Controls.Add($HopsTxtbox)) | Out-Null
$controls.Add($inputpanel.Controls.Add($HostTxtbox)) | Out-Null
$controls.Add($inputpanel.Controls.Add($HostLbl)) | Out-Null
$controls.Add($outputpanel.Controls.Add($textBox)) | Out-Null




#############################################################################################################################



                           # Add event handler for radio buttons
                $global:PingradioButton.Add_Click($NDEventHandler)
                $global:DNSradioButton.Add_Click($NDEventHandler)
                $global:TraceradioButton.Add_Click($NDEventHandler)

                # Define event handler
              $NDEventHandler = {

                    UncheckAllRadioButtons $section2
                    UncheckAllRadioButtons $section3
                    UncheckAllRadioButtons $section4
                    UncheckAllRadioButtons $section5

                    


                    
                    if ($global:PingradioButton.Checked) {
                    Add-SectionWithControlsToPanel -Panel $panel2 -Controls $controls -SectionLocation (New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)) -SectionSize (New-Object System.Drawing.Size($panel2.Width, $panel2.Height))
                    $textBox.Clear()
                    $HostTxtbox.Clear()
                    $HopsTxtbox.Clear()
                    $CountTxtbox.Clear()
                    $HopsLbl.Visible = $false
                    $HopsTxtbox.Visible = $false
                    $CountLbl.Visible = $true
                    $CountTxtbox.Visible = $true
                    $HostLbl.Visible = $true
                    $HostTxtbox.Visible = $true
                    $textBox.Visible = $true
                    $form.Controls.Add($panel2.Controls.Add($trackbar))
                    $form.Controls.Add($panel2.Controls.Add($ZoomlabelPlus))
                    $form.Controls.Add($panel2.Controls.Add($ZoomlabelMinus))

                        
                    } elseif($global:DNSradioButton.Checked) {
                    Add-SectionWithControlsToPanel -Panel $panel2 -Controls $controls -SectionLocation (New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)) -SectionSize (New-Object System.Drawing.Size($panel2.Width, $panel2.Height))
                    $textBox.Clear()
                    $HostTxtbox.Clear()
                    $HopsTxtbox.Clear()
                    $CountTxtbox.Clear()
                    $HopsLbl.Visible = $false
                    $HopsTxtbox.Visible = $false
                    $CountLbl.Visible = $false
                    $CountTxtbox.Visible = $false
                    $HostLbl.Visible = $true
                    $HostTxtbox.Visible = $true
                    $textBox.Visible = $true
                    $form.Controls.Add($panel2.Controls.Add($trackbar))
                    $form.Controls.Add($panel2.Controls.Add($ZoomlabelPlus))
                    $form.Controls.Add($panel2.Controls.Add($ZoomlabelMinus))
       

                    }
                      elseif($global:TraceradioButton.Checked){
                    Add-SectionWithControlsToPanel -Panel $panel2 -Controls $controls -SectionLocation (New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)) -SectionSize (New-Object System.Drawing.Size($panel2.Width, $panel2.Height))
                    $textBox.Clear()
                    $HostTxtbox.Clear()
                    $HopsTxtbox.Clear()
                    $CountTxtbox.Clear()
                    $HopsLbl.Visible = $true
                    $HopsTxtbox.Visible = $true
                    $CountLbl.Visible = $false
                    $CountTxtbox.Visible = $false
                    $HostLbl.Visible = $true
                    $HostTxtbox.Visible = $true
                    $textBox.Visible = $true
                    $form.Controls.Add($panel2.Controls.Add($trackbar))
                    $form.Controls.Add($panel2.Controls.Add($ZoomlabelPlus))
                    $form.Controls.Add($panel2.Controls.Add($ZoomlabelMinus))


                    }
                }


# Adjust panel sizes on form resize
$form.Add_Resize({
    $totalWidth = $form.ClientSize.Width
    $totalHeight = $form.ClientSize.Height
    $panel1Width = [math]::Round($totalWidth * 0.5 / (0.5 + 2 + 0.5))
    $panel2Width = [math]::Round($totalWidth * 2 / (0.5 + 2 + 0.5))
    $panel3Width = $totalWidth - $panel1Width - $panel2Width
    
    $panel1.Width = $panel1Width
    $panel1.Height = $totalHeight

    $panel2.Width = $panel2Width
    $panel2.Height = $totalHeight
    $panel2.Left = $panel1Width

    $panel3.Width = $panel3Width
    $panel3.Height = $totalHeight
    $panel3.Left = $panel1Width + $panel2Width
})#






# Add the panels to the form
$form.Controls.Add($headerLabel)
$form.Controls.Add($UserheaderLabel)
$form.Controls.Add($pictureBox)
$form.Controls.Add($panel1)
$form.Controls.Add($panel2)
$form.Controls.Add($panel3)
$form.Controls.Add($panel2.Controls.Add($ExecuteButton))
$form.Controls.Add($panel2.Controls.Add($ClearButton))
$form.Controls.Add($panel2.Controls.Add($ExportButton))

# Show the form
$form.ShowDialog()




I tried placing the event handlers first before the form is loaded but its still not working properly

I would test it in regular powershell instead of the ISE. Let us know what it looks like from a real powershell console host.

Any further updates

I checked via Powershell console.Upon selecting any radio button still not loading any controls.

Your form doesn't work at all for me, so I can't really help you. https://imgur.com/a/2zRO4pf
